# No puedo actualizar variables con setState dentro de axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-axios

Estoy desarrollando una consulta a una api usando **axios** con **react**. Las respuestan llegan correctamente pero no estoy **pudiendo actualizar el estado de una variable, que muestra errores desde el servidor o login correcto**

En la consola, me diceque el operador **this** es no definido.

El code de mi funcion es la siguiente:

```
consumirApiLogin() {
    const payload={
        "_username":this.state.username,
        "_password":this.state.password,
    }
    axios.post(API_LOGIN, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            this.setState({errorApi: response.data})
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            let error = '';
            if(e.response)
            {
                let error = e.response.message;
            }
            this.setState({errorApi: error})
        });
}
```

Mi constructor es el siguiente:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = ({
        username:'',
        password:'',
        errors: {},
        errorApi: ''
    })

    this.cambioUsername = this.cambioUsername.bind(this);
    this.cambioPassword = this.cambioPassword.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit   = this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 
    this.consumirApiLogin = this.consumirApiLogin.bind(this);
    this.validarFormulario = this.validarFormulario.bind(this);
}
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida!Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que te saltaste algunos conceptos de JavaScript antes de empezar con React y uno de estos es el que te está causando problemas.

En JavaScript, toda función (no arrow function) tiene un contenedor o bolsa conocida como **contexto** o **scope**. Cuando tu usas `this` dentro de una función en realidad estás haciendo referencia a este contenedor o a contenedores superiores (chaining). En este caso, estás haciendo uso de `this` dentro de un **callback**, un callback no tiene un contexto superior, por ende, `this` siempre hará referencia al mismo contexto del callback.

```
this.setState
```

En realidad está haciendo algo como:

```
[callback].setState
```

Porque como expliqué arriba, **this** hace referencia al contexto en donde se llama. ¿Qué es lo que tienes que hacer para solucionar el problema?

Simple, convertir tu callback a *arrow function*:

```
.then((response) => {
  this.setState({errorApi: response.data})
})
```

Lo mismo para el `catch`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las observaciones y la respuesta!